# php exec() not refreshing Path environment variable

Tags: java, php, variables, path, environment

I upgraded my java jvm, and they changed the way they store the location of the jvm in the PATH environment variable.

It sticks "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;" at the beginning of the Path variable.

Now, the problem is that when I do exec("java blah blah blah"), php can't find the new path.  I get

```
"'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
```

It only works if I do the full path:

```
exec("c:\My\Path\To\Java\java blah blah blah")
```

When I do phpInfo(INFO_ENVIRONMENT), it shows the Path variable from before the change.  Is it being cached somewhere?  I read in other threads that restarting the server, or restarting Apache would help, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I tried multiple restarts.

var_dump($_SERVER['PATH']), var_dump(getenv('PATH')) seem to show the NEW path.  Why would the value in phpInfo be different?  Is there a separate copy of the Path variable somewhere?

I have a development environment that I tested on Windows Vista, and I don't have this problem.  When I test it on a windows 2008 environment, I get the problem.

I'm trying to avoid hard coding the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before the exec statement you can add the path to the path variable like so

```
putenv('PATH='.getenv('PATH').'path to java here');
```

Comment: But then, I'm just avoiding hard coding it in one spot, by hard coding it in another spot.

I'm trying to get my code to work whether the Jvm is updated or not.  And the path to the jvm is changed during the update.  I'd like solution that's more elegant, than configuration it separately on separate servers.  It would be nice if it just reads the Path environment variable.  

Any ideas why it seems to be storing 2 copies of the Path variable?

Comment: The only thing that i can think of is that you have more than one php.ini there is one for the version of php that you are using and one that Apache loads in the phpinfo you should see something like loaded configuration file ensure that it is loading the correct one that you made the changes to

Comment: At first, I tried what you suggested.

    putenv('PATH='.getenv('PATH').'path to java here');  

But then, what I noticed that that phpInfo shows the NEW path along with what I just appended.

So then, I changed it to just:

    putenv('PATH='.getenv('PATH'));

Now, phpInfo() shows the new Path.  

So then, I thought that maybe, it just got unstuck.  Maybe it was just cached somewhere, and needed to be updated??  I remove that line of code, and phpInfo() seems to revert back to the old copy of Path.

Adding that line of code works for me.